# how to do if else class in link using php

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

how to do if else class in link using PHP

i want to add condition in class how can i do this please help me to fix this issue

thanks

```
if ($user == 'brother' ) {

echo "<img src=\"images/bandmember.jpg\" class=\"right\" >";
} else {
    echo "<img src=\"images/gismember.jpg\" class=\"left\" >";
}
```

It will Showing Result Like This

```
<img src="images/bandmember.jpg" class="right">
<img src="images/gismember.jpg" class="right">
```

and i want to Result Like This

```
<img src="images/bandmember.jpg" class="right">
<img src="images/gismember.jpg" class="left">
```

here is complete code

```
<?php

include 'db.php';


   $sql = 'SELECT * FROM users';

   if($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
      if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {


         while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<div class=\"container\">";


              if ($row['username'] == 'brother' ) {

    echo "<img src=\"images/" . $row['photo'] . "\" class=\"right\" >";
    } else {
        echo "<img src=\"images/" . $row['photo'] . "\" class=\"left\" >";
    }

        echo "<span class=\"time-right\">" . $row['username'] . "</span>";

            echo "</div>";
         }
         mysqli_free_result($result);
      } else {
         echo "No records matching your query were found.";
      }
   } else {
      echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($con);
   }
   mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Please add the code that produces the actual result. The code you have only prints html for 1 image at a time.

Comment: Add your original code and output. Right now your out put not match with your code

Comment: replace left with right, no ?

Comment: i update complete code

Comment: You want to alternate from `right` to `left` and so on? Or just first "right", and "left" after?

Comment: i have only two user so i want to set if user is this then it will right or else left

Answer (score 0):

You could use a variable to store the class value, and change it after the first iteration.

```
$class = 'right' ;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<div class=\"container\">";
    if ($row['username'] == 'brother' ) {
        echo "<img src=\"images/" . $row['photo'] . "\" class=\"$class\" >";
    } else {
        echo "<img src=\"images/" . $row['photo'] . "\" class=\"$class\" >";
    }
    $class = 'left'; // change from 'right' to 'left'
```

Or you can use a boolean and invert it on each iteration. Then use a ternary condition to create "left" or "right" class:

```
$right = true ;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<div class=\"container\">";
    if ($row['username'] == 'brother' ) {
        echo "<img src=\"images/" . $row['photo'] . "\" class=\"".($right?'right':'left')."\" >";
    } else {
        echo "<img src=\"images/" . $row['photo'] . "\" class=\"".($right?'right':'left')."\" >";
    }
    $right = !$right; // invert each time
```

Comment: Is this something like this you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Try This make sure it's helpful for you.
thank You

```
<?php include 'db.php'; $sql = 'SELECT * FROM users'; if($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
  if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {


     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<div class='container'>";


          if ($row['username'] == 'brother' ) {

echo "<img src='images/'" . $row['photo'] . "class='right'>";
} else {
    echo "<img src='images/'" . $row['photo'] . "class='left' >";
}

    echo "<span class='time-right'>" . $row['username'] . "</span>";

        echo "</div>";
     }
     mysqli_free_result($result);
  } else {
     echo "No records matching your query were found.";
  } } else {
  echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($con);  }  mysqli_close($con); ?>
```